# JavaScript asynchronous loader

Tags: javascript, ajax

Which module (not library) works best in Drupal 7 (they support corresponding libraries), labjs or headjs? Which is one better written, tested, and with less bugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [LABjs](http://drupal.org/project/labjs) and [HeadJS](http://drupal.org/project/headjs) are recent modules, actively developed by professional Drupal developers, both are offering versions for Drupal6 and 7 and both have less than 100 installations (see statistics).

Also both are aware of each other modules and collaborate together, [see](http://drupal.org/node/1017186)

Because they are so recent modules and you can't know how well they will be supported later in the future, I would  base my decision on which JS library fits your needs. Probably I would trust more on [LABjs](http://labjs.com/), that is much more tested and used (twitter, vimeo, etc are using it), plus it's a library focused in JavaScript loading, nothing else.

[HeadJs](http://headjs.com) library in the other hand also is offering other features: detecting CSS3 features, detecting screen resolution, etc something that can be good or not, depending what you are looking for. And also HeadJS is better integrated in the Drupal ecosystem: integration with Boost, CDN, Advagg modules.

If you are interested in this topic, I would recommend you a must read [blog post](http://blog.getify.com/2010/12/on-script-loaders/) from the author of LabJS to get a inside view of the technology under these JavaScript loaders (LABjs, HeadJS, ControlJS from Steve Souders, etc )

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have installed labjs. Views admin UI ajax features are broken. Could that be a fault of labjs?

Comment: It seems was an issue http://drupal.org/node/1080898, maybe only fixed in the dev version? You could continue there in the issue queue better.

Comment: it was jquery cdn module fault